# Result of "ls" in grub prompt

Tags: grub2

I have just installed grub to an HDD and using it for a new virtual machine in Virtualbox.

When trying to start the virtual machine Im getting this:

> error: no such device: 9ce773ae-22ef-41d4-a88f-6868e7baa11 Entering
>   rescue mode... grub rescue>

So I have searched about that error and there are like a lot of information.

My doubt is: when I run `ls` I'm getting this:

`(hd0)`

whilst in other sites I visit talking about that error the result of `ls` has more elements, like this:

`(hd0) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0, msdos3)`

What does the number of elements mean? in my case with just one element, is *everything* ok?

**EDIT**: it is supposed I have to partitions in that HDD:

```
NAME   FSTYPE              SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                        1.4T            
├─sda1 linux_raid_member     2G            nas2:0
└─sda2 linux_raid_member   1.4T            nas2:1
```

Comment: The elements are the partitions. It looks like the disk is not partitioned.

Comment: Hard to say what you mean by "everything ok" - what are you trying to achieve? Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: @jeremiah well, the next step should be running this 4 commands on the grub prompt: `set root=(hd0)`, `set prefix=(hd0)/boot/grub`, `insmod normal`, `normal` and I wanted to know if everything will be ok before running them, or if something will be wrong because of the "poor"/different result of `ls`

Comment: @guillermochamorro but it is strange what you say because I have two partitions in that HDD. I have edited my question.

Comment: Can you run a ```> ls (hd0,1)```?

Comment: You may not have those other disks (msdos disks) if you're on a Linux box.

Comment: @jeremiah it says "no such partition"